# BKSendGSEvent ERROR

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an IOS app using Unity3D. My issue is that when I run the app on the new iPad (iOS 6.0), the app will have freezes and then suddenly run perfectly fine again several times throughout. The log shows the following:

```
Jan 22 15:33:42 New-iPad backboardd[51] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
```

This issue only occurs on the new iPad. I've tried testing on iPod 5th gen (iOS 6.0.1), and older devices like iPad 2 (iOS 5.1.1) and none of them have this issue.

Has anybody else met with such problems? I am at my wits end for debugging and any suggestions to shed light on this would be of immense help!